# Where can we download diff files for Magento 1.9.2.0?

Tags: upgrade, ce-1.9.2.0

Where can we now download diff files for the latest Magento 1.9.2.0? They were always at 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/download/diff but there's nothing new there. They don't publish diff files any more?

Comment: i guess someone who is responsible for that page is on vacation (summer, right??), or you need to wait, cause it was just released...

Answer (score 2):

see from any github mirror https://github.com/speedupmate/Magento-CE-Mirror/commit/2da79109217c28d17b3cb9cb8ef69586deb93699 or create you own git mirror of magento and get the diffs

Answer (score 1):

You can generate your own.  Just download a copy of the older version you want to diff against, and a copy of `1.9.2.0`.  Then use the `diff` command

```
diff -r magento-ce-1.9.1.0/ magento-ce-1.9.2.0/ > magento.diff
```

This will generate a diff file `magento.diff`

Alternatively, use a mirror: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/compare/cf43f51aab6125f03a0083df1c00ac0f34b86c86...cb52550f2aa31026dfa9cb95709c567ebe3fded7.diff